# How to display HTML in android app for this code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "rendered", "renderedcont"},
                new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.content});
                //new int[]{R.id.title});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

How I can show the text with HTML supported?
Here is the full code:

```
package com.codespeedy.jsonreader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView lv;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();
}


private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "JSON Is Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "https://www.eyeswift.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
               // JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray jsnarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < jsnarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsnarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String date = c.getString("date");
                    String type = c.getString("type");
                    String link = c.getString("link");
                    String author = c.getString("author");
                   // String gender = c.getString("title");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject title = c.getJSONObject("title");
                    String rendered = title.getString("rendered");
                    JSONObject content = c.getJSONObject("content");
                    String renderedcont = content.getString("rendered");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("date", date);
                    contact.put("author", author);
                    contact.put("link", link);
                    contact.put("rendered", rendered);
                    contact.put("renderedcont", renderedcont);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "rendered", "renderedcont"},
                new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.content});
                //new int[]{R.id.title});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


  }
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: Here is the code: new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.content}); . I don't want to show HTML code in content. I need to convert HTML code. I mean it should support HTML code instead of showing code.

Comment: all right, if you don't want to show html markup, then you can instead use webView or you would have parse it to show in list. For parsing you should generate in JSON format which then would be more easy to parse for your android application and generating it on the server side is more easy too.

Comment: I have already parsing it from JSON and it is showing HTML markup in textview. I want to make it HTML supported.

Comment: I have edited my question and you can see the full code

Comment: well, there is no way that you can have textView that supports html. you need to do it on your own by complex code.

Comment: look, i think you are having problem with links or perhaps with images right?  do it using another textView for linke and ImageView for your images. but you need to  download images over internet

Comment: What is the code for that?

Comment: go ahead, learn and try it on your own....